# Typescript Omit Accepts Wider Types

Tags: typescript, types, utility

Typescript allows the following, wondering if is this by design?  I was thinking it should not be allowed to return
a *"wider"* `Point` inside a function that wants to return `Omit<Point, 'whatever'>`.

```
interface Point {
    x: number,
    y: number
}

function getPoint() {
    return { x: 3, y: 9 }
}

function ohNo(): Omit<Point, 'y'> {
    // is allowing this to compile "by design"?
    return getPoint()
}

const p = ohNo()
console.log('oh no', p)
```

Playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHtRmQbwFDKHIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtADQFECe5Vd0eAvnnjJRAIwwdCGQBzCGAxYAFAEpczQlGmUo4nCXIBmBsjbIAnL179Bw0ePQALAHLpF5APLVgYADyzwBgOQsfgB8ykTIamAa4lIymOCKPHwIYgDO2AAOyAC8yHaOCckgKegANhAAdCXoEnJ+dhTofgbpCkA)

Comment: Yes, it is by design

Comment: You’re using the term “wider” backwards from the type system convention.  Object types in TS are open, so `{a:0}` accepts any value with the right `a` property, including all those values of type `{a:0, b:0}`, so the former is wider than the latter.  Adding properties to an object type narrows it, and removing properties widens it.  Indeed, `{}` is the widest possible object type in TS and allows any object values.

Comment: @jcalz You're right, my bad. 